# Как типизировать объект Error и Error cause?

Tags: typescript

Помогите типизировать объект ошибки и `Error cause` в замороченной функции.

TypeScript ругается в этом месте:

```
  throw new Error(
    FETCH_ERROR_MESSAGE,
     { cause: { status: response.status } }
  );
}
```

Текст ошибки:

> Type '{ status: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Error'. Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'status' does not exist
> in type 'Error'.

Как/где указать тип `cause`? Непонятно от слова совсем как расширить тип `Error`.

Вторая ошибка в блоке catch. Я хочу указать там тип например `Error` но Typescript ругается и пишет:

> Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if
> specified.

Поэтому я указал там `any`, но хочется типизировать.

Функция:

```
async fetchProducts({ commit, dispatch }, attempt: number = 1) {
      try {
        commit(MutationTypes.SET_IS_LOADING, true);

        const response = await fetch(BASE_URL);

        if (!response.ok) {
          await wait(1000);
          throw new Error(
            FETCH_ERROR_MESSAGE,
             { cause: { status: response.status } }
          );
        }

        const products: Product[] = await response.json();
        commit(MutationTypes.SET_PRODUCTS, products);
      } catch (e: any) {
        commit(MutationTypes.SET_IS_LOADING, false);

        if (attempt <= FETCH_ATTEMPTS_COUNT) {
          commit(MutationTypes.SET_ERROR, {
            isError: true,
            message: e.message,
            errorCode: e.cause.status,
            timeout: attempt * (FETCH_DELAY_REQUEST_MS / 1000),
          });

          await wait(attempt * FETCH_DELAY_REQUEST_MS);
          return dispatch('fetchProducts', attempt + 1);
        }

        commit(MutationTypes.SET_SERVER_STATUS, { isDown: true, message: SERVER_ERROR_MESSAGE });
      } finally {
        commit(MutationTypes.SET_IS_LOADING, false);
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых у `Error` либо 0 либо 1 аргумент и он должен быть строкой. Во вторых вы можете просто выкинуть свой кастомный объект, наприммер так:

```ts
type MyErrorBody = {
    cause: {
        status: string
    }
}

class MyError {
    #errorText: string;
    #errorBody: MyErrorBody;

    constructor(errorText: string, errorBody: MyErrorBody) {
        this.#errorText = errorText;
        this.#errorBody = errorBody;
    }

    get errorText(): string {
        return this.#errorText;
    }

    get errorBody(): MyErrorBody {
        return this.#errorBody;
    }
}

try {
    throw new MyError('Error text', {
        cause: {
            status: 'Bad request'
        }
    });
} catch(e) {
    const error: MyError = e as MyError;

    console.log(error.errorBody.cause.status); // "Bad request"
}
```